React native IOS build cant find libraries in Derived Data directory
I am coming back to a React Native project which used to build and now is not.
I have tried the following;

Updateing react/react native
Removing and re-installing node modules
Remove and reinstalling cocapods
Updating cocapods
Cleaing the build directory
Removing and resetting the library search paths in xcode
Updating the IOS build target in both xcode and the Podfile

The probelm I am having is when I build the project I see that it cannot find the DoubleConversion library.
After some investigation it turns out this is just the first library it cannot find so errors on this one. During a pod install I can see it installing the DoubleConversion library.
This is the output I get from running the IOS build command. Note the build output is the same building from the terminal or via xcode.
yarn ios
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 15 Pro'
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Found Xcode workspace "myperks.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 15 Pro (iOS 17.0)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace myperks.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myperks -destination id=D95E730E-FB5A-4D9A-8404-0189D398D230")
Ignoring digest-crc-0.6.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine digest-crc --version 0.6.4
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.8.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.8.2
▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
▸ Running script 'Start Packager'
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Linking myperks
⚠️  ld: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'
⚠️  ld: search path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/usr/lib/swift' not found
⚠️  ld: search path '/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myperks-gdtrvukhkrhlaydznulsqeffucrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion' not found
⚠️  ld: search path '/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myperks-gdtrvukhkrhlaydznulsqeffucrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly' not found


There are more libs it fails to find but it cut it off there for the example.
What I noticed is the directory that the build in looking in for libs doesnt actually exist.
/Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myperks-gdtrvukhkrhlaydznulsqeffucrm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator

The above exists, however inside this is another dir named after the app e.g. myperks.app, this has a few buits and a Frameworks dir but does not have RCT-Folly for example.

Seeing that the error is caused by the Test Target, as a workaround I have selected TestTarget only for "Test" in the "Build tab" (following this guide). For this solution I have based myself on these answers:

2020
2017

